# Why we need implicit Application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am creating an application using Play Framework and Scala and that application using implicit

> play.api.Application

why we need this application in our scope?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an architectural choice that was made by the developers. There are certain components of the framework that require a reference to an `Application` (typically the current running `Application`). The Cache, DB, Messages (i18n), Evolutions, and WS API are the first ones that come to mind.

The `Application` trait is an integral part of a running Play app. It is meant to hold the application configuration, routes, references to plugins, the `GlobalSettings` object, application logging, etc.

For example, when I call:

```
DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    ...
}
```

I need to have `play.api.Play.current` in scope (the current running `Application`). Why? It knows which `DBApi` is loaded, and other database configuration options, should they be needed.

Similarly, when I call `play.api.cache.Cache.set(...)`, I need an implicit `Application` in order for the cache API to figure out which cache plugins are loaded, and which one to use.

Why don't these APIs just all reference the current running `Application`? Beats me, really. It would definitely hurt modularity to have a hard-coded `Application` reference everywhere. I suppose you may be able to have multiple running applications for tests, etc. I remember reading that `play.api.Play.current` may be going away in future versions to eliminate the need for keeping global state, though I cannot find the source.

Comment: It's on the roadmap for 3.0: https://docs.google.com/document/d/11sVi1-REAIDFVHvwBrfRt1uXkBzROHQYgmcZNGJtDnA/pub